# Does remote copy with scp support the -E flag?

Tags: rsync, scp

In [this documentation page](https://support.apple.com/guide/terminal/move-and-copy-files-apddfb31307-3e90-432f-8aa7-7cbc05db27f7/2.10/mac/10.15) section titled "Copy a file or folder remotely", Apple says `scp` supports the -E flag, which preserves extended [file] attributes, resource forks, and ACL information.

On none of my Macs does scp support this flag. Is this a documentation error or is it really supported?

Comment: Can confirm this for newer macOSs: tested 10.11.6 > 10.13.6. **The flag works for 10.11.6 > 10.11.6**. The online docs 10.13-10.15 mention the -E flag. The man pages of 10.13-10.15 don't mention it though.

Comment: It looks like that document is just out of date. I looked through [the source Apple publishes](https://opensource.apple.com), and it appears the `-E` option was removed in 10.12.0. Or, more accurately, it wasn't re-added when they switched from the OpenSSH 6.9 codebase (used in 10.11.x) to OpenSSH 7.2 (in 10.12.0); `-E` was a nonstandard Apple addition, and I suspect they just didn't bother to port it to version 7. But note that `rsync -E` is still there, so you can use that instead.

Comment: "Can confirm this for newer macOSs: tested 10.11.6 > 10.13.6.": This was ambiguous & I meant: Can confirm that the flag doesn't work for newer macOSs: tested 10.11.6 (source) > 10.13.6 (destination) which failed.

Comment: Just as an alternative rsync over ssh should be equivalent and should support extended attributes, RF and ACLs. https://explainshell.com/explain/1/rsync

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I'll use `rsync` then. When moving to a new mac, do you guys usually want to maintain Resource Forks? (not even sure what they are actually)

Comment: @julien_c Resource forks are very rare these days, but `-E` is also needed to preserve a variety of other filesystem metadata so you should still use it.

Comment: I've used `rsync -X`.